# Restart Application pool worker process if it fails or hangs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8, application-pool

I have a asp.net mvc application deployed in IIS. The application pool associated to the app has 1 worker process set as maximum.

I have observed that sometimes application pool worker process freezes/hangs and I need to restart manually the pool in order to start working correctly again.

So I am wondering if there is a way to configure worker process in order that when it hangs it automatically restarts. If so, how?

As far as I know, if worker process hangs, then application pool also hangs, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

short answer is you can look into the process model -> Ping settings in application pool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel

But i think you need to isolate the reason for the hang and fix the root cause of the issue.
SImple steps you can start are below
1) Check if there are any entries in application and system event logs.
2) At the server level in IIS under worker processes -> click on your worker process and check the requests that are hung, it might give you some idea.(Might reuire installation of tracing and request monitor feature in IIS)
3) You can use debug diag to collect manual dumps when issue is happening and analyze within debug diag to get the call stack of the long running requests

Comment: In step 2) if I click on worker process it does not show the requests... Do I need to install tracing and request monitor feature in IIS?

Comment: yes you need request monitor to be installed to view the current requests in a worker process